# Payant, oui mais qui paie ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

> **PAYANT** : adjectif et nom - 1260 « qui doit être payé »<sup>1</sup>
>
> 1. Qui paie : *spectateurs payants*, ...
> 2. Qu'il faut payer: *Billet payant*, ...
> 3. (Figuratif) Qui paie, qui profite qui rapporte (synonymes : lucratif, rémunérateur, rentable) : *Le coup n'est pas payant*, ...

Dire : « C'est payant » ne dit pas dans quel sens le paiement s'effectue  : est-ce que je débourse une somme, est-ce que je perçois quelque chose ?

Selon les contextes ci-dessus :

- en 1, je suis spectateur : l'entrée est payante, je paie ;
- en 2, je suis caissier : j'encaisse ;
- en 3, je fais des affaires : c'est rentable (je ne débourse rien).

Donc le sens 1 est opposé au sens 2, parce que l'on considère les deux côtés de la transaction, mais le sens 1 est le contraire du sens 3 alors que je considère la transaction du même point de vue :

« C'est payant, ce spectacle » : Je paie, ou, on me paie, pour y aller ?

*N.B. suite au commentaire :*
Si je vais à un spectacle où on me paie, c'est à dire que l'on rétribue ma présence, pour être figurant ou faire la claque à l'opéra, je ne débourse rien, et pourtant je suis toujours spectateur :

> Pour moi, c'est payant d'aller à l'opéra on a même l'entrée gratuite !

Y a-t-il d'autres mots qui recouvrent une telle ambiguïté ?

---

***EDIT**

Mots trouvés*

- Hôtes (commentaire de Random) ;
- Louer, sanction (réponse ci-après de Chop) ;
- Plus, apprendre (réponse ci-après de Philippe Carriere) ;
- Sanctionner, proroger (réponse ci-après de Michel Floc) ;

*Exemples dérivés, syllogismes, contradiction & opposition apparente...*

- "Qui paye ses dettes, s'enrichit." (commentaire de PapaPoule) ;

---

<sup>1 - Définition du petit Robert.</sup>

Comment: Il y a eu tout un sujet sur "hotes" récemment, qui désigne autant les invités que les les personnes qui reçoivent...

Comment: Pour moi, c'est pas si ambigue... Dans tous les cas, ca indique une transaction. La dernière ne traite pas d'argent, mais plus d'investissement divers, par exemple, en temps. Le terme s'applique plus à une transaction qu'a un des deux cotés

Comment: @StevenBENET le point que marque cl-r pour moi est sur le sens de "entrée payante". Grammaticalement, c'est l'entrée qui devrait payer. or c'est le spectateur qui paye l'entrée...

Comment: Le sens 3 n'implique absolument pas que je ne débourse rien.

Comment: @Relaxed J'ai complété ma question pour prendre en compte votre remarque : il n'y a pas forcément une notion d'investissement dans le sens 3.

Comment: @cl-r Oui mais ce n'est pas ce à quoi le sens 3 fait référence. À la rigueur, un figurant pourrait dire que sa présence au spectacle est payante mais, sauf jeu de mot visant à obscurcir délibérement le propos, il ne dire pas que le spectacle est « payant », il dira que c'est « payé » ou utlisera une autre tournure. Et puis si on me paie pour aller à un spectacle à titre professionel, peut-être que mes frais sont couverts et que l'opération est payante pour moi mais quelqu'un débourse quand même le prix du ticket, ce n'est pas ce dont il s'agit.

Comment: L'exemple me semble complétement artficiel et maladroit, est-il seulement attesté quelquepart ? Il est en tous cas intéressant de noter qu'au contraire du simple « c'est payant », il n'y plus dans ce cas la moindre ambiguïté, il est ici question du sens 3 et du profit personnel (pécunier ou non) du locuteur et pas du prix du billet. Où est donc la difficulté ou la particularité à analyser dans cet exemple ?

Comment: Quelques opinions quant aux usages : l'utilisation dans le sens 1 me paraît très rares. Même en ayant organisé des événements, je ne l'ai jamais entendu ou employé. N'est-il pas désuet ? Concernant le sens 3, l'exemple ajouté n'a pas été convaincant, mais je pense que l'usage courant pour cette définition est d'utiliser un indicatif présent : « Ça paye. » Ces deux définitions me font davantage penser à des définitions du participe présent de « payer » (sens 1 : le sujet paye ; sens 3 : simple question de tournure) alors que l'adjectif est généralement admis avec le sens 2.

Comment: @Chop L'exemple 1 est tiré du Robert, cela correspond à *entrée gratuite* contre *entrée payante*, il est aussi utilisé dans *télévision payante* (Origine de cette question http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14611/t%c3%a9l%c3%a9vision-%c3%a0-p%c3%a9age/14613?s=3|0.4289#14613 : le commentaire de Gilles et les corrections que j'ai apportées). J'ai choisi des exemples masculins pour que l'interrogation soit plus prégnante. Mais à la lecture d'une phrase de ce style, utilisé souvent par les humoristes, on ne peut déduire le sens, et, l'on n'a pas forcément sa duplicité en tête.

Comment: @cl-r Dans l'exemple 1, le spectateur doit payer. Dans vos autres exemples (entrée, télévision), c'est toujours le spectateur qui doit payer, pas le nom en sujet. Je ne doute pas de la justesse de l'exemple, seulement de son usage qui me semble peu courant.

Comment: @Chop Pour le moment je n'ai que *hôte* comme autre mot pouvant prêter à contre sens... à croire que l'humour anglais ne traverse pas la Manche... ou qu'on ne lit plus Desproges, l'Oulipo et autres nombreux génies joueurs de mots qui révèlent (verbe relié à génies ou à mots ?) des infinis ... indéfinissables par nature :)

Comment: @cl-r Il est vrai que j'ai tellement de lecture en retard qu'effectivement, je n'ai pas encore pu me consacrer aux jeux de langue (_La Disparition_ figure aussi sur la liste de ce qui doit être intéressant à lire). Mais les seules chansons françaises que j'apprécie encore sont celles où les auteurs sont capables de jouer avec les mots de notre belle langue. :)

Comment: @Relaxed Pour répondre à vos différents commentaires, ma question démarre d'une erreur que j'ai faite dans une de mes réponses sur ce site, et aussi de recherches sur le quiproquo, l'humour des jeux de mots (sans les sous-entendus que l'on déplore parfois), l'approche des limites, un travail sur la transcription de l'oralité, de ses rythmes, intonations, contextes ... et donc ses ambiguïtés.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26796/discussion-between-cl-r-and-chop).

Comment: Tough crowd! Anyway, for what it's worth, from an anglo point of view, I see the ambiguities and like your question.  Again from my anglo (read: "probably totally wrong") take, I even see all three senses of "payant" in the proverb "[Qui paye ses dettes, s'enrichit](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/qui-paye-ses-dettes-s-enrichit.php)." = "payer les dettes (leurs remboursement) est payant pour celui qui paye et pour celui qui est payé."

Comment: Cette question part dans tous les sens. Il n'y a absolument aucun jeu de sens ou ambiguïté dans “qui paye ses dettes, s'enrichit”, juste une invitation moraliste à payer ses dettes au sens le plus littéral. Si le but est de trouver des mots avec deux sens diamétralement opposés comme « louer », il conviendrait de nettoyer la question et probablement de retirer tout référence à « payer » qui ne fonctionne absolument pas comme ça.

Comment: @Relaxed La seule question posée : "Y a-t-il d'autres mots qui recouvrent une telle ambiguïté ?" et le choix de l'illustrer par *payant* est explicité dans un de mes commentaires-réponses. Il y a plus de logique dans la confrontation des mots dettes et enrichissement que de jugement moral... et ce n'est pas un oxymoron, comme "une douce violence".

Comment: @cl-r Sauf que « telle » fait référence à tout le reste et qu'il n'y a rien de « tel » dans les exemples avec « payant ». D'où une grande confusion, totalement inutile, quand « louer » ou « hôte » pourrait illustrer tout cela beaucoup plus clairement. Si la question est plus générale, pourquoi s'obstiner à justifier le choix initial par des commentaires un peu fumeux, des exemples erronés et des raisonnements tarabiscotés quand une solution toute simple existe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Y a-t-il d'autres mots qui recouvrent une telle ambiguïté ?

« Hôte » [a déjà fait le sujet d'une demande de traduction](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9586/7224) et [sa dualité a déjà causé la perplexité d'intervenants sur ce site](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14422/7224).

cl-r cite ici « payant ».

Le livre [*Pièges du langage* par Jean-Pierre Colignon & Pierre-Valentin Berthier](https://books.google.lu/books?id=BE7EgJMQNmQC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=dualit%C3%A9+du+mot+h%C3%B4te&source=bl&ots=nU6C4Ad7a-&sig=5juSaFKbE3GcYfADhjSJGMTIDbw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBWoVChMIgPPgstGexwIVBbkUCh35IQBQ#v=onepage&q=dualit%C3%A9%20du%20mot%20h%C3%B4te&f=false) cite au moins deux autres exemples.

#### Louer

Inutile de s'attarder sur ce bien connu : le verbe s'applique aussi bien au propriétaire qu'au locataire.

> je *loue* un appartement à celui qui me le *loue*.

Ainsi que mis en avant par [Papa Poule](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/6011/papa-poule), cet exemple peut par ailleurs s'apparenter à « payer » comme proposé dans la question, grâce à son troisième sens, qui n'est pas rattaché aux deux autres : faire les louanges de quelqu'un.

Cette définition présente un risque moins important de confusion et descend d'une racine différente (*laudere* contre *locare*), mais l'exemple n'en demeure pas moins intéressant.

#### Sanction

La dualité est ici d'une nature différente, recouvrant l'aspect de la sanction « punition » et celui du diplôme marquant la consécration.

> Le baccalauréat est la *sanction* des études supérieures ; le gouvernement prend des *sanctions* contre des émeutiers, des spéculateurs.

#### Conclusion

Oui, il existe d'autres mots. D'autres réponses complèteront certainement cette (très courte et non exhaustive) liste.

Comment: +1 (cast earlier), especially for “louer,” which although arising from different Latin roots (laudere vs locare), exhibits further similarity to @cl-r ‘s original, 3-sense, example with its third (laudere/expression of admiration) sense.

Comment: @PapaPoule I didn't even think of it. Thanks for this, I will include it immediately!

Answer (score 3):

> Y a-t-il d'autres mots qui recouvrent une telle ambiguïté ?

En plus de « Hôte » et de « Louer » (qui ont déjà été mentionnés), en voici d'autres:

### **Plus**

> Il y en a plus (ce qui veut dire qu'il y en a davantage).

vs

> Il n'y en a plus (ce qui veut dire qu'il n'en reste pas).

### **Apprendre**

> Je suis professeur et j'apprends à mes élèves.

vs

> Je suis un élève et j'apprends de mon professeur.

Comment: Along the lines of your 'plus' example, I often find myself being misunderstood when I ask "Il y a **personne**?" before barging into the bathroom without waiting long enough for an answer! (+1, cast earlier)

Comment: Bien que l'on m'a toujours dit que l'utilisation d'« apprendre » dans le sens d'« enseigner » était impropre, le Wiktionnaire valide cette définition. Bien joué !

Answer (score 2):

Pour « sanctionner », le Trésor informatisé de la langue française (TILF) cite une phrase de Chateaubriand assez ambigüe pour qui ne connaît pas l'Histoire de France : « le refus de Louis XVI de sanctionner la proscription des prêtres ».

Autre ambigüité en droit consitutionnel, « proroger » : d'après le TILF, « proroger une assemblée » peut signifier suspendre ses séances, mais aussi prolonger la durée du mandat de ses membres.

Comment: J'ai intégré votre réponse dans l'EDIT de ma question --- Il faudrait préciser dans votre réponse que *sanctionner* peut avoir pour synonyme *confirmer, approuver légalement ou officiellement "Le baccalauréat sanctionne les études scolaires", consacrer, entériner, homologuer, ratifier* ; il a aussi le sens d'*adopter, consacrer :"Mot sanctionné par l'usage"* et comme sens opposé : *Punir d'une sanction* ---[Source le Petit Robert].

Comment: « Sentir » est aussi ambigu. Dans « Marie sent la framboise », Marie respire-t-elle ou émet-elle l'odeur de framboise ?

Answer (score 1):

L'analyse ne me semble pas très convaincante. « C'est payant » fait très probablement référence au sens numéro 2, à la rigueur au sense numéro 3 mais en aucun cas au sens numéro 1 car « c'est » fait référence à une chose, pas à une personne.

Il n'est pas non plus question de caissier ou de direction, peut-être que le spectateur paie, que quelqu'un d'autre paie pour lui, que la place a été payée d'avance mais qu'on soit en plus payé pour y aller ou non, ça signifie simplement que l'entrée n'est pas gratuite. Bien sûr, on peut y voir un manque de précision mais c'est comme dire “coloré” ou “rose” à la place de “rose bonbon”. En fait, on dit souvent « c'est payant » sans référence à une transaction particulière, par exemple pour signifier que l'entrée n'est pas libre et qu'en fait on n'ira pas.

La seule ambiguïté possible serait entre le sens 2 et le sens 3, comme si un exposant disait

> Aller au salon de l'auto, c'est payant.

Mais les deux peuvent très bien être vrai en même temps (je paye pour y aller mais je m'y retrouve parce que je fais des affaires), il n'y a pas non plus de vraie opposition et on a simplement affaire à un jeu sur le sens littéral et le sens figuré d'un mot, ce qui ne me semble pas particulièrement inhabituel.

Comment: J'ai complété ma réponse avec un exemple sur l'opéra : organisme à entrée payante, donc à la base je débourse, en fait je suis payé pour y aller, alors que je suis toujours spectateur : il y a donc une forme de syllogisme qui ne montre pas votre réponse.

Comment: @cl-r J'ai donné moi-même un exemple similaire mais je ne vois justement pas du tout où est le syllogisme là-dedans. Il y a simplement deux sens distincts qui peuvent éventuellement se superposer mais il n'est absolument pas question du prix du ticket dans le sens 3.